# simplify predictive posterior distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Is it possible to simplify the following expression into a Gaussian distribution on y? (getting rid of the integrals on w).

$$
p(y|x,w_1,w_2) = \int^{10}_{-10}\int^{10}_{-10} Normal((w_1x+w_2x),1)p(w_1)p(w_2)dw_1dw_2 \\
p(w_1) = Uniform [-10,10] \\
p(w_2) = Uniform [-10,10]
$$

Here's my attempt: 
$$
x_v := [x,x] \\
\int Normal(w^Tx_v,1) p(w) dw \\
\propto \int exp\{ -\frac{1}{2} (y-w^T x_v)^2 \}dw \\
\propto \int exp\{ -\frac{1}{2} (y^2 - 2w^Tx_vy + (w^Tx_v)^2) \}dw
$$
Now, I attempt to separate $w$ and $y$ into two exponentials, so that I can move the exponential of $y$ out of the integral of $w$.

$$
w^Tx_vx_v^Tw - 2w^T(x_vy) + y^2 \\
= (w^TLw - 2w^TLm + m^TLm) - m^TLm + y^2 \\
L = x_vx_v^T \\
m = (x_vx_v^T)^{-1}x_vy
$$
However, I'm stuck here because the last expression of $m$ doesn't work: $x_vx_v^T$ is NOT invertible.

Comment: Just one way:  numerically.  (And you might want to define what you mean by $Normal....$ and where is $y$ on the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: Newbie here. What do you mean by numerically? Can you share any useful links on it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: I don't want to calculate the numerical value. I want to transform the expression into the form of a Gaussian in y.

Comment: You might get more help if you used more standard notation.  And how does $y$ pop into the equations?